# Normalization of Probability distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, statistics, normalization

I need to Know.
Is it a condition that Probability density is bounded between 0 and 1?

Comment: I plotted a probability density versus the position and I got the maximum of the probability to be 1.25

Comment: This is a question about mathematics (probability) not physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil Hmm... Is a question about quantum probabilities a mathematical question or a physics question?  I think this is an important realization for people who are learning to do QM calculations. +1

Comment: @BillN Is the question "What is 1+1=?" a question about physics just because addition is used in every branch of physics? The context of QM is not relevant to this question, and for that reason I think it is mathematics not physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil Just because a question is off-topic here doesn't mean it is on-topic somewhere else. Please don't vote to migrate bad/unclear questions. Rather, just vote to close, but leave it here. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. For example, a uniform distribution in the interval $[0,1/2]$ has a probability density of $2$ everywhere in that interval.

Along the same lines, a uniform distribution in the interval $[0,1/n]$ has a probability density of $n$ everywhere in that interval, for any positive $n$. So probability density has no upper bound at all.